# Can also link yaw rate sensor data with map

Tags: navigation, kinect, camera, gmapping, rate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using gmapping to map the aera with my robot,
I am presently using odo data and data from kinect for mapping.

**update after dornhege answer**

I get the odo ticks from the robot, which I convert to the distance travelled by each wheel and theta, which I get from the difference of the distances travelled by wheels divided by wheel base length. I give this to /odom.

Presently I am using this published /odom data for the mapping and navigation.

I even Have a yaw rate sensor on the robot which gives yaw angle (along with acceleration values), How can I use this with robot_pose_ekf which also accepts Roll and Pitch angles, but I only have yaw angels how can I achieve the fused odo data with yaw using robot_pose_ekf.?

Many thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190699/can-also-link-yaw-rate-sensor-data-with-map/) by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2014-08-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-26**:
You would just set roll and pitch to 0. Yaw angles are the important ones for slam.

**Comment by [ROSuser007](https://answers.ros.org/users/51166/rosuser007/) on 2020-01-23**:
**Warning**: A **yaw rate** sensor's output is not an angle [rad] or [°], it is an **angular velocity [rad/s] or [°/s]**.
P.S: I am aware the question is more than 5 (five) years old, but it can still be found and probably continues to confuse people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The cmmon way is to filter odometry with yaw, e.g. by robot_pose_ekf and use this as odometry for gmapping.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on 2014-08-20**:
any example showing how to do this...

**Comment by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on 2014-08-26**:
I have modified the question, can you please re-vist the question.